# Fundamental Group of $\mathbb{R}^3\setminus S$ where $S$ is the unit circle in the $x-y$ plane.

Tags: general-topology, fundamental-groups

I have been asked to find the fundamental group of $\mathbb{R}^3\setminus S$ where S is the unit circle in the $x-y$ plane. I have started to use Seifret-Van Kampen and so I constructed the spaces:
$$U=\mathbb{R^3}\setminus\{(x,y,0)\in\mathbb{R^3}:x^2+y^2\leq1\}$$
$$V=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R^3}:x^2+y^2<1,|z|<1\}$$
That is, the real 3-plane with the unit disk removed, and the open cylinder. Both of these spaces are simply connected, but I'm confused as to how to find $\pi_1(U\cap V)$ as it is two disjoint cylinders and so I can't use Seifret-Van Kampen as they have an empty intersection.

Comment: $U$ had been used in multiple examples in the notes as a part of using S-VK, should I bring this up to the lecturer? I had essentially been taking it as a given but you're obviously correct when considering the definition of an open subset.

Comment: Why is it not a cover? If our set is $\mathbb{R^3}\setminus \{(x,y,0)\in\mathbb{R^3} : x^2 + y^2=1\}$ then all the elements removed by the unit disk in $U$ are "added back" with the cylinder $V$, with the exception of exactly the elements $\{(x,y,0)\in\mathbb{R^3} : x^2 + y^2=1\}$ as the cylinder is open no?

Comment: I'm very sorry, it turns out I have overlooked the $\mathbb{R}\setminus$ at the beginning of your $U$, so I was thinking you were trying to do something wrong. What you have asserted is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that does not uses S-V theorem directly.

First, the space is homotopic to the 2-dimensional sphere where two poles are identified (try to imagine this), which is again homotopic to the wedge sum of $S^2$ and $S^1$. Hence S-V theorem gives $\pi_1(X) \simeq \pi_1(S^1) * \pi_1(S^2) \simeq \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Did you mean to say a 2-sphere (I.e. $S^2$, the sphere in 3 dimensions) Or do you mean the 2-dimensional sphere a.k.a. a circle?

Comment: I mean the $S^2$. Actually I’ve never heard that circle is called 2-dimensional sphere.